# Summing Cell arrays?

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

ok so I have 10 different matrices stored in a KNEW each of which is different, KG is a (12x12) matrix. The first row and column of KNEW is like a coordinate system for the placement in KG as you can see. So this works for storing the right values in the correct placement of KG. But I get an over write when I do this. say for example KNEW{10} & KNEW{1} has the same coordinate system for which I want to store that element in KG in that coordinate. my code only keep's KNEW{10} in KG. How do I sum them as I go along?

```
 'KG=zeros(2*NJ,2*NJ) 
***I tried doing a sum KG at the end but that didnt work Not sure about how to do this?
 for jj=1:NM
   for q1=2:5
    for q2=2:5
      KG([KNEW{jj}(q1,1)],[KNEW{jj}(1,q2)])=[KNEW{jj}(q1,q2)]
    end
end
```

end

Comment: I tried doing a [SUM(cell2mat(KNEW{jj}(q1,q2)] but that didnt work

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to do, nor what a KNEW is... Maybe you could explain a bit more?